# Is this convergence test correct?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

For what values or $ r \in \mathbb{R}$ does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n}{n^n}$ converge?

I have thought of this proof, but is it correct?

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r^n}{n^n}$ can be proven to converge $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}$ with Cauchy root test:

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt[n]{\left| \frac{r^n}{n^n}\right|}) = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} {\left|\frac{r}{n}\right|} = \frac{\left|r\right|}{\infty} = 0 < 1 \implies$ The sum converges $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct.

Comment: Instructors who don't understand the number $\infty$ and that would like to pretend to be strict, might complain about you writing $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|r|}{\infty}$. If you remove that step you will make them happy.

Comment: @owl Sorry, fixed it now, I think.

Comment: It wasn't really wrong before. It was only a risk if you have obtuse instructors, like leaving $\frac{1}{(-1)!}$ in a summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

Using the Cauchy root test, as the result of the limit is less than 1, the sum converges.

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sqrt[n]{\left| \frac{r^n}{n^n}\right|}) = 0 < 1 \implies$ The sum converges $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}$